# "npm" is not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm

So, I am trying to use command prompt for something. But it isn't working.

The steps were, get Node.js. Download a dropbox file of what I need. Copy the path thing that I use to get to the file in File Explorer.

Turn on Command Prompt type in "cd C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\GoAniFire-master_10.zip" and it worked.

I have Node installed, but then when i type in "npm install" after i hit enter on the last step. Nothing besides a error saying "npm isn't recognized" pops up, I have no idea what to do as I am new to Node.js and only recently started using command prompt. ;-;'

-Nate

Comment: download npm and node officially from their site which will automatically set environment path for your windows machine.

Comment: Are NPM and Node two seperate things?

Comment: Yes, they are. NPM is a package manager that allows you to download JS packages while Node allows you to run JS in your machine. 

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Node installer includes the NPM package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Node from the official site, you should already have the Node Package Manager. You're likely receiving this error because Node isn't in your Path, so your command prompt doesn't know what it's looking for.

- Open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
- In "User variables" or "System variables" find the variable Path. (If it doesn't exist, create it.)
- Add your node.js folder path at the end of the variable value, beginning with a semicolon separating it from previous values. e.g. `;C:\Program Files\nodejs`
- Restart your command prompt.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed node. Try restarting your computer first. If that doesn't work follow what user Elo wrote.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced
   System Settings -> Environment Variables
2. In User variables find variable PATH and add path to nodejs. Usually
   -> C:\Program Files\nodejs;. If variable doesn't exists, create it.
3. Restart PC and IDE.
4. If you're using VSCode, close old terminal and open a new one. Even
   when I did everything VSCode could not see node + npm, because old
   terminal was broken.